# Find the name of an Arduino sketch programmatically?

Tags: arduino, eeprom

I would like to determine the name of the Arduino sketch running on my Arduino Leonardo.  This is so when I provision the Arduino I can change the file name and have the sketch automatically change a number in the script.

Is this possible?

To give an idea of why we're doing this, we have to provision 50 Arduinos and rather than hand-edit a bunch of scripts, I would rather just change the file name.

I have no idea how to do what I am looking to do, but as a show of good faith for onlookers here is the code in which I set the EEPROM on an Arduino:

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include "EEPROMAnything.h"

// begin EDIT ME

char CONFIG_NUMBER[]="##"; // Config Number goes here

// end EDIT ME

char IPADDRESS[]="XX.XX.XX.XXX";
char APN[]="myapn";

const int buflen = 32;

struct config_t {
  char model[buflen];
  char serial_num[buflen];
  char ipaddress[buflen];
  char apn[buflen];
}configuration;

int ee_addr=0;


boolean registrationDone = false;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println(F("Starting Up"));

}

void loop()
{
  config_t configuration;
  strcpy(configuration.model, MODEL);
  strcpy(configuration.serial_num, SERIAL_NUM);
  strcpy(configuration.ipaddress, IPADDRESS);
  strcpy(configuration.apn, APN);
   if (!registrationDone){
    EEPROM_writeAnything(ee_addr,configuration);
  registrationDone = true;
  }
  EEPROM_readAnything(ee_addr, configuration);
  Serial.println(F("Settings"));
  Serial.println(String(configuration.model));
  Serial.println(String(configuration.serial_num));
  Serial.println(String(configuration.ipaddress));
  Serial.println(String(configuration.apn));
  delay(5000);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas!
Sara

Comment: So what you're trying to do is have 50 Arduinos all running the same script but with some identifying number uploaded to them to tell them apart? Do you have to do this by changing the filename (would a different solution - which doesn't involve changing the script - suffice)?

Comment: Yep - I like skinnyTOD's solution as it does this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this [code](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=e6ea3602ee7e2ec6af9e4556a3e65033&topic=118605.msg893130#msg893130) but it appears to do what you are wanting to do.

Seems to me though like an easier to maintain solution would be to use an external .h file which defines an ID number and then include that in your sketch. You could then write a desktop macro to increment the number defined in the .h file before provisioning each board.

Comment: Awesome!  I am currently provisioning Arduinos so this sounds like the answer to me.  Thanks so much!